# how to I deal with error CS1502 when converting string to list of numbers with Select and Int32.Parse method

Tags: c#, string, list

So as I said in the tittle, I have the string, which contains numbers.

For example `("8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4")`.

And I know I have to use `Int32.Parse` and `Select` method to convert it.

I searched several topics(however only like one or two were in C#) that could be helpfull to me. Technically I found the solution - `stringArray.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();` - but I don't understand how to implement it. When I don't change the arguments and only replace "stringArray" with the name of the given string, I am getting an error "`error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles)' has some invalid arguments`

I haven't found anyone with similiar problem, and I have no idea how to solve this(have been dealing with this for few hours now)

Comment: Is your string `var s = "8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4";`?

Comment: `stringArray.Split(new [] {' '}).Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList()` should work better...

Comment: If the string is like above, even `var res = s.Split().Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();` will work.

Comment: @Sani Singh Huttunen Well, theorethically it worked, because compiller has no problems with that... Yet it doesn't quite solve my case, apparently. After this line, my string should be a List now, so when i use Max() and Min() from Linq - it should return me the maximum and minimum value, but it doesn't(or rather it does, but it returns the values according to ASCII order)

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Case solved, I know what I did wrong. Apparently I am retarded, and for some reason I was still putting the string's name to Max() and Min() instead of the new variable that was linked with this(in this case "res").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a string like

```
string s = "8 3 -5 42 -1 0 0 -9 4 7 4 -4";
```

You have to split in in an array with

```
var arrayOfStrings = s.Split(' '); // Space is the seprator here
```

And after that, you can convert them to int values with

```
var intList = new List<int>();
foraech (var _int in arrayOfStrings) 
{
   intList.Add(Int.Parse(_int));
}
```

or in a more secure way

```
var intList = new List<int>();
foraech (var _int in arrayOfStrings) 
{
   int temp = 0;
   if(Int.TryParse(_int, out temp)) 
   {
      intList.Add(temp);
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried that, but it solved nothing(same errors). Should i provide you with the whole code?

Comment: [link](http://scr.hu/2u99/kblny) - code;
[link](http://scr.hu/2u99/scwiv) - from compiler

Comment: Ok. That was my bad. it should be `var arrayOfStrings = s.Split(' ');`. I edit my answer. Split needs as argument a char not a string.

Comment: This time compiler swallowed it, and apparently it's all good, but for some reason it apparently still behaves as if it were a string(so the order of values still behaves as if it was according to ASCII - so 9 is MAX and ' ' is MIN)

Comment: Okay, nevermind, case solved. It's just my stupidity for still putting the "numbers" name instean of the new variable name(that was my new list) in Min() and Max() method.